# C++ Finish Current task before moving on to the next

Tags: c++, curl, ofstream

Im trying to find a way to download a file and have the program wait for the download to finish then move onto the next task which  in this case would be checking to see if the file exist

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    char *url = "http://199.91.153.180/y1plsynnb11g/e9g9mcd3fi5txov/UHC.jar";
    char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "UHC.jar";
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://199.91.153.180/y1plsynnb11g/e9g9mcd3fi5txov/UHC.jar");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    ofstream launch;
    launch.open("UHC.jar");
    if (launch.is_open()){
        cout<< "File Downloaded";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Download Failed";
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `char *` to point to a string literal, use `const char *`.

Comment: This code should do exactly what you describe.  `curl_easy_perform` shouldn't return until the operation is complete.  So, what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that once it finishes it says file downloaded then the file is there just empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized what was wrong when it to check for the file existing using ofstream it was trying to write to it so it would make the file empty. Just changing it from ofsteam to fstream it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP request may have failed. Try adding error checking before /* always cleanup */

```
if (res)
  cout << curl_easy_strerror(res) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized the return value of write_data is wrong. But it should have caused an error...
Anyway, please try:

```
size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written * size;
}
```

Comment: It did create an error but I disregarded it. No  more error but still my original question still stands It is just downloading an empty file.